# How to pass data to a PDF page building function

Tags: flutter

I am building my first Flutter application.

I have this function being called from a floating action button in a screen but can't figure out how to pass a data object into this function.

Can anybody help? The function won't accept any parameters.

I call the function like this:

I call it like this:

```
                         FloatingActionButton(
                                heroTag: 1,
                                backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Printing.layoutPdf(onLayout: buildReceipt);
                                  },
                                child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.print),
                             ),
```

Here is my code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart';

Future<List<int>> buildReceipt(PdfPageFormat format)  async {

final Document pdf = Document();

pdf.addPage(MultiPage(

  pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4.copyWith(marginBottom: 1.5 * PdfPageFormat.cm),

  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,

  header: (Context context) {

    if (context.pageNumber == 1) {
      return null;
    }

    return Container(

        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,

        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 3.0 * PdfPageFormat.mm),

        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 3.0 * PdfPageFormat.mm),

        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            border:
                BoxBorder(bottom: true, width: 0.5, color: PdfColors.grey)),

        child: Text('Portable Document Format',
            style: Theme.of(context)
                .defaultTextStyle
                .copyWith(color: PdfColors.grey)));
  },
  footer: (Context context) {
    return Container(
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 1.0 * PdfPageFormat.cm),
        child: Text('Page ${context.pageNumber} of ${context.pagesCount}',
            style: Theme.of(context)
                .defaultTextStyle
                .copyWith(color: PdfColors.grey)));
  },
  build: (Context context) => <Widget>[
        Header(
            level: 0,
            child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('Portable Document Format', textScaleFactor: 2),
                  PdfLogo()
                ])),
        Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10)),
        Paragraph(
            text:
                'I want to display this ${data}')
      ]));

  return pdf.save();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you can change your code to this

```
FloatingActionButton(
                                heroTag: 1,
                                backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Printing.layoutPdf(onLayout:(format)=> buildReceipt(format, data1, data2, data3));
                                  },
                                child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.print),
                             ),
```

Then change also your function to match method call

```
Future<List<int>> buildReceipt(PdfPageFormat format, data1, data2, data3)  async {
//bla bla bla
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,
This is my button, where I'm passing the name to the PDF page

```
OutlinedMButton(
  text: 'PDF', 
  onTap:() async{
  final v =  await PdfGenerate.generate(name: "Rahul");
  html.Blob blob = html.Blob([v], 'application/pdf');
  final url = html.Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob(blob);
  html.window.open(url, "_blank");
  html.Url.revokeObjectUrl(url);
   },
  ),
```

This is my PDF page

```
class PdfGenerate{
static Future<Uint8List> generate({
required String name
})async{
final pdf = Document();
pdf.addPage(
MultiPage(
build: (context) => [
Text(name)
]
)
);
}
}
```